# How to call a second query on parse.com AFTER the first query is completed (cloud code)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

My challenge is that I need to do one query before the other, using the result of the first query as input in the second query.

```
var adList = [];
query.find({
success: function(results)  {
    for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
        var ad = [];
        ad.push(results[i].get("Type"));    //Adds "Type" to the ad array
        objectIDArray.push(results[i].id);  
    }
},
error: function(){
    response.error("failed");
}   
});
    //second query
var locations = Parse.Object.extend("Locations");
query2.include("locationID");
query2.containedIn("campaignIDString", objectIDArray);
query2.find({
    success: function(results){
        locations = results2[0].get("locationID");
        adList.push(locations.get("CITY"));
        adList.push(locations.get("PROVINCE"));
        adList.push(locations.get("STORE_ADDRESS"));

        response.success(adList);
    }, error: function(){ 
        response.error("failed to get a response");
        }
});
```

as you can see, in the second query I need the objectIDArray, which is populated by the first query. If I run this I always get null result in the second query because both queries seem to happen in parallel. In any case they dont happen sequentially like I had hoped.
How do I make my second query run after the first one? use promises?

Can you give me an example, I couldnt understand that very well form the documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the second query into the completion block of the first query:

```
var adList = [];
query.find({
success: function(results)  {
    for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
        var ad = [];
        ad.push(results[i].get("Type"));    //Adds "Type" to the ad array
        objectIDArray.push(results[i].id);  
    }

    //second query
    var locations = Parse.Object.extend("Locations");
    query2.include("locationID");
    query2.containedIn("campaignIDString", objectIDArray);
    query2.find({
        success: function(results){
            locations = results2[0].get("locationID");
            adList.push(locations.get("CITY"));
            adList.push(locations.get("PROVINCE"));
            adList.push(locations.get("STORE_ADDRESS"));

            response.success(adList);
        }, error: function(){ 
            response.error("failed to get a response");
            }
    });
},
error: function(){
    response.error("failed");
}   
});
```

Or you can use [Promises](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises).

Comment: I did, but I get  Failed with: TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined at the line adList.push(locations.get("CITY"));
How to solve that?